# Issue while creating dynamic components in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am creating a chat screen where i have two components one for sent message and another for received message. when the user sent a message a new sent message component gets created and added to the main component and similar to received message. But after the first message when i am trying to enter another message (which creates another sent message component with the newly typed message) it is updating the older components also. I am using resolveComponentFactory and ViewContainerRef to achieve this.

**chat-screen.component.ts**

```
 @ViewChild('messagecontainer', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) entryRef: ViewContainerRef;
  private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(@Inject(ChatOtOService) private chatOtoService: ChatOtOService,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    // Message received event subscription
    this.chatOtoService.newMessageReceivedEvent.subscribe((newMessageReceived: {rcvdMsg: string, rcvdId: string}) => {
      this.receivedMessage = newMessageReceived.rcvdMsg;
      this.receivedMessageId = newMessageReceived.rcvdId;
      this.now = new Date();
      this.chatOtoService.allReceivedMessages.push({ rcvdMsg: this.receivedMessage, rcvdId:this.receivedMessageId});
      this.createReceivedComponent();
    });

    // Message sent event subscription
    this.chatOtoService.newMessageSentEvent.subscribe((newMessageSent: {sentMsg: string, sentId: string}) => {
      this.sentMessage = newMessageSent.sentMsg;
      this.sentMessageId = newMessageSent.sentId;
      this.now = new Date();
      this.chatOtoService.allSentMessages.push({sentMsg: this.sentMessage, sentId: this.sentMessageId});
      this.createSntComponent();

    })
  }

/** this is to create a new sent message component **/
  createSntComponent() {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MsgSntComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.entryRef.createComponent(factory);
  }

/** this is to create a new received message component **/
  createReceivedComponent() {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MsgRcvdComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.entryRef.createComponent(factory);
  }
```

**chat-screen.component.html**

```
<ng-container #messagecontainer></ng-container>
```

[chat screen layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1L8H.png)
Please help me out

Comment: can you please change `@ViewChild` to `@ViewChildren` and try ?

Comment: tried using it, but it is not working.